# How to set roles permission of a channel? - Java JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

How can I set the permissions of a list of roles in a test channel?
I tried to this but it set only the last role:

```
            Category category = guild.getCategoryById(Categ);
            TextChannel channel1 = guild.createTextChannel("ticket-" + EndlessBungeeTickets.instance.sql.getTicket(username)).setParent(category).addPermissionOverride(guild.getMember(user), EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE), null).addPermissionOverride(guild.getPublicRole(), null, EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE)).complete();
            //RolesWR is equal to a list of roles for ex. [738036146151358504, 814517406067589122, 789617469605281843]
            //But it only sets permission to the last role of the list
            RolesWR.forEach(ruolo -> {
                System.out.println(ruolo);
                channel1.getManager().putPermissionOverride(guild.getRoleById(ruolo), EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE), null).queue();
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add all your overrides before calling queue.

```java
Category category = guild.getCategoryById(Categ);
TextChannel channel1 = guild.createTextChannel("ticket-" + EndlessBungeeTickets.instance.sql.getTicket(username)).setParent(category).addPermissionOverride(guild.getMember(user), EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE), null).addPermissionOverride(guild.getPublicRole(), null, EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE)).complete();
ChannelManager manager = channel1.getManager();
for (long roleId : RolesWR) {
  manager.putPermissionOverride(guild.getRoleById(roleId), EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE), null);
}
manager.queue(); // this will add all overrides at once
```

Even better would be to just add them all on the [ChannelAction](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/restaction/ChannelAction.html) directly:

```java
String ticketId = EndlessBungeeTickets.instance.sql.getTicket(username);
// Use variables to make the code more readable and remove duplicate allocations
EnumSet<Permission> permissions = EnumSet.of(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL, Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE);
// Use the channel action properly by adding all overrides to it
ChannelAction<TextChannel> manager = category.createTextChannel("ticket-" + ticketId)
  .addPermissionOverride(guild.getMember(user), permissions, null) // grant access to the user
  .addPermissionOverride(guild.getPublicRole(), null, permissions); // deny access to @everyone
for (long roleId : RolesWR) { // Make sure IDs are stored as longs
   // grant access to the roles
  manager.addPermissionOverride(guild.getRoleById(roleId), permissions, null);
}
// Creates the channel with the overrides already applied, without blocking your thread too!
manager.queue();
```